# Capture coordinates of the click in a web browser window on Windows machine

Tags: java, windows, browser

I am not sure if we need our own custom browser for this.
If we do, what is your recommendation for open source browser?

We need application that is able to capture location of user clicks on the web page in the browser on Windows machine (cross-platform would be a huge plus).  Store the coordinates in the file.

Later be able to open browser on that webpage and do the click screencapturing and reading the URL of the new page that user will be taken too.

Any idea on how to implement this? What libraries, open source projects could help us?
Can this be done in Java?  C?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This could work for you: (Taken from this website [here](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-mouse-co-ordinates-when-element-clicked/))

```
$('#mouse-click').click(function(e){
    $('#mouse-xy').html("X: " + e.pageX + " Y: " + e.pageY);
});
```

This uses jQuery which I think you may like. After that you could use [AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/Ajax/Default.Asp) to send the mouse click results back to your server and save that information in a file.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery will achieve this for you, if you put this code inside your page,

```
    $('#mouse-click').click(function(e){
       var x = e.pageX;
       var y = e.pageY;
});
```

jQuery is a JavaScript framework that you'll find will run in most browsers, certainly all the mainstream ones.

From there, you'll need to tell us what platform your developing on for us to give you any guidance on how you can make use of any of this.